# Spring boot не работает с phpmyadmin

Tags: spring

У меня есть Андроид приложение интернет магазина, у которого бэк работает на spring boot. Когда я тестировал приложение на своем домашнем ПК (на винде), все работало, но после того, как я перенес это на сервер под линукс, теперь phpmyadmin не может работать вместе со спрингом. Если установлен phpmyadmin, то Spring выдает killed при запуске, если запущен Spring и попытаться установить phpmyadmin, выходит Aborted. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А они не могут просто на одном порте запускаться?

Comment: Мало информации. У вас на этапе установки проблема или на этапе запуска? Если последнее - то может конфликт портов? Если первое - то, наверное, надо бы указать что у вас за ОС (дистрибутив, версия etc)